# How many parts can an atom be split into?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

I know how a nuclear explosion is made, but can an atom be split further than ionising?

Comment: keywords "Nuclear Fission" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission

Comment: http://htwins.net/scale2/ Interesting stuff to dive in to

Comment: Search term: 'deep inelastic scattering'. A very inclusive (heh!) phrase that covers cases when the nucleus is ripped in to a shower of hadronic junk. However, you'll want to be clear on what an atomic nucleus is and it might help to have some familiarity with quarks and quark confinement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionising an atom is not the same as "splitting" it. When an atom is ionised, that means that one or more electrons are removed (or added) from the electron shells around the nucleus. When ionised, an atom does not become a different [element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element), not even a different [isotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope), because the nucleus of the atom does not change. Ionisation only affects the chemical activity of the atom.

When a heavy nucleus like $^{235}U$ ([uranium-235](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235))is split ([fissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission)), the nucleus itself breaks up into smaller pieces, such as Krypton and Barium nuclei. This is what releases the energy in an atom bomb. Note that in a hydrogen bomb fission is only used to trigger the fusion of Hydrogen nuclei into Helium nuclei.

Radioactive nuclei also undergo decay, in which the nucleus releases particles like electrons (beta radiation) or helium nuclei (alpha radiation). In this case the nucleus does change and you get a different isotope or element. However, this is not considered fission. With fission the pieces are much larger: alpha particles have a mass of 4 [atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_mass), Krypton has mass 92 and barium is 141.

Comment: Your understanding of a hydrogen bomb is off - the large majority of the energy is still from uranium or plutonium fission.

Comment: Fission bombs are typically < 50 kT; the most powerful was 500 kT. Fusion bombs went up to 50 MT.

Comment: I am aware of that. Again, the hydrogen fusion (D-T fusion produces about 18MeV of energy) serves as a neutron source. Uranium fission (the result of that neutron) produces about 180MeV and additional neutrons. Plus the secondary is held together a bit longer than the primary so fission continues several more neutron generations. The (neutered) Tsar Bomba _perhaps_ generated more fusion than fission energy.